# Angular7. Enviar cookie en la cabecera al servidor

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

Quiero enviar una cookie al servidor (SpringBoot), pero cuando la mando, en la pestaña network parece que no se adjunta la cookie.

Angular ->

```
  cook() {
    this.cookie.set('cookiePrueba', 'valorPrueba'); //se crea
    const pathExec = 'http://localhost:8080/enviarCookie'; // ruta para enviar
    return this.http.post<any>(pathExec, this.cookie.get('cookiePrueba')); //se envía
  }
```

Se agrega en un apartado "payload" que no sé que es.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente el código del servidor que lo recupera:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/enviarCookie")
public String enviarCookie(HttpServletRequest req) {
 System.out.println(req.getCookies());
 System.out.println ("llego");
 return "llego";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Los parametros del método post son (url,body,options) en la llamada de angular estás enviando en el cuerpo (body) la cookie que mencionas, no conosco spring pero revisando la documentacion podrías revisar si funciona con @RequestBody

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/enviarCookie")
 public String enviarCookie(@RequestBody String value) {
 System.out.println(value);
 System.out.println ("llego");
 return "llego";
}
```

El payload que ves en la pestaña network son los parametros que viajan en el body de la petición

Si quieres enviar en los headers tu cookie podrías intentar agregandola en angular con algo como esto

```
cook() {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'ejemplo': this.cookie.get('cookiePrueba') });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.cookie.set('cookiePrueba', 'valorPrueba'); //se crea
  const pathExec = 'http://localhost:8080/enviarCookie'; // ruta para enviar
  return this.http.post<any>(pathExec,{}, options); 
}
```

La cual podrías obtenerla de la siguiente manera

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/enviarCookie")
 public String enviarCookie(@RequestHeader(value="ejemplo") String cookie) {
 System.out.println(cookie);
 System.out.println ("llego");
 return "llego";
```

}

Comment: Gracias por comentar, se me olvidó añadir el @RequestBody, pero, en el lado del cliente, sigo con problemas de añadir la cookie a la cabecera http, y ahora que puse el @, obtengo el error 415...

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, dale una revisada

Comment: "owner": "typescript",
 "code": "2345",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo \"{ headers: Headers; }\" al parámetro de tipo \"RequestOptionsArgs\".\n  Los tipos de propiedad 'headers' no son compatibles.\n    El tipo 'Headers' no se puede asignar al tipo 'import(\"d:/MiTutorialHeroes/node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers\").Headers'.\n      Falta la propiedad 'keys' en el tipo 'Headers'.",
 "source": "ts",

}

Comment: Estás haciendo el import Headers de @angular/http ?, algo así **import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';**

Comment: Sí, aunque ya vi que estaba obsoleto, luego me estuve peleando con el RequestOptions que no le gustan los parámetros, lo dejé por imposible.